# Can Kibana just show all matching documents in a table?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

I have an ELK stack with log entries coming from Logstash into Elasticsearch. In Kibana, I would like to make a simple "visualization" that just shows the text of all log messages matching a particular saved search. For example, a table of all today's log messages that say "error". This would be similar to seeing the results in the "Discover" section of Kibana, but easier to read.

I thought the "Data Table" visualization might do this, but it still seems to require an "aggregation" such as the total number of error messages.

Can you tell me whether this is even possible, and if so, whether there's any documentation that explains how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [save a search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#save-search) in the Discover section, with [field columns in the Document table](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/discover.html#adding-columns), so you can visualise all the message from the matching documents (well the first 500).